# How do I configure Tensorflow Serving to serve models from HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, tensorflow, hdfs, tensorflow-serving

I'm attempting to serve Tensorflow models out of HDFS using Tensorflow Serving project.

I'm running tensorflow serving docker container tag 1.10.1
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/serving

I can see tensorflow/serving repo referencing Hadoop at
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/628702e1de1fa3d679369e9546e7d74fa91154d3/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD#L341

```
"@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop:hadoop_file_system"
```

This is a reference to

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc

I have set the following environmental variables:

- HADOOP_HDFS_HOME to point to my HDFS home (/etc/hadoop in my case).
- MODEL_BASE_PATH set to "hdfs://tensorflow/models"
- MODEL_NAME set to name of model I wish to load

I mount Hadoop home into docker container and can verify it using docker exec.

When I run the docker container I get the following in logs:

```
tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:369] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error: Could not find base path hdfs://tensorflow/models/my_model for servable my_model
```

I have found examples of Tensorflow doing training using HDFS, but not serving models from HDFS using Tensorflow Serving.

Can Tensorflow Serving serve models from HDFS?
If so, how do you do this?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/359

Answer (score 1):

In `BUILD` of `model_servers`, under the `cc_test` for `get_model_status_impl_test`, add this line `@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop:hadoop_file_system`, as shown below:

```
cc_test(
    name = "get_model_status_impl_test",
    size = "medium",
    srcs = ["get_model_status_impl_test.cc"],
    data = [
        "//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata:saved_model_half_plus_two_2_versions",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":get_model_status_impl",
        ":model_platform_types",
        ":platform_config_util",
        ":server_core",
        "//tensorflow_serving/apis:model_proto",
        "//tensorflow_serving/core:availability_preserving_policy",
        "//tensorflow_serving/core/test_util:test_main",
        "//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:saved_model_bundle_source_adapter_proto",
        "//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_config_proto",
        "//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_source_adapter_proto",
        "//tensorflow_serving/test_util",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/cc/saved_model:loader",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/cc/saved_model:signature_constants",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:test",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop:hadoop_file_system",
    ],
)
```

I think this would solve your problem.

Ref: [Fail to load the models from HDFS](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/359#issuecomment-295565538)